# how can use javascript in c++

Tags: javascript, c++, internet-explorer-8

I am working on the IE8 extension I am using ATL project for that propose
now i am facing a problem that i dont know how to use my javascript code in that project 
any body who know about it please tell me

Comment: Can you clarify what exactly you want  to do? Do you want to embed a javascript engine inside your extension?

Answer (score 2):

You could try [SpiderMonkey](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/SpiderMonkey)